# Change for loop condition statements based on another condition in c

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-statements

i want to make statements in for loop condition based on another condition. E.g. Given two numbers a and b, if a>b I want to put condition of i-- and otherwise i++. This can be done with two for statements in if, but I want to do it with one for loop only.

something like this..

```
for(i=a; if(a>b),put i>=b here else put i<=b; if(a>b) put i-- here else i++)
{
     some code...
}
```

I tried this :

```
for( i = a; ( a > b ? i >= b : i <= b ); ( a > b ? i-- : i++ ) )
{
   ...
}
```

But it didn't worked.
Can I get some some help regarding it?

UPDATE : This was not working on some online compiler. Same code works fine in local machine. Solved.

Comment: is `a` or `b` changed in for loop?

Comment: Your code looks ok - have you tried it?

Comment: I was trying in one online compiler, where it was not working. I tried in local codeblocks, its working. Don't know why that happened. Thanks @artm

Comment: Post an [mcve], then.

Comment: @jigar It works as intended but I don't get problem you got .

Comment: @ameyCU, It was the problem with online compiler. I realized it is working with local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was not working on some online compiler. I tried to use it in local machine in codeblocks. It is working as intended. I don't know why it was not working on  online compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a condition such as

```
i += (a > b) ? 1 : -1
```

Or

```
i += (a > b)-2*(a <b)
```

exploiting a> b having a truth integer equivalent of 1 or 0.

Or you could rewrite the loop, depending on what you're trying to achieve:

```
aa = a < b ? a  : b;
bb = a < b ? b  : a;
for (i = aa; i < bb; i ++)

if (a < b) {
    for (i = a; i < b
 else 
    for (i = a; i > b; i--
```

If the code in the loop is not very complex you can duplicate it, and if it is , you won't lose so much performance by wrapping it inside a function and call it from the two loops. You will gain in understandability and maintainability of the code.

Comment: That is new way. But it will increase number of for loops. I just wanted to use one for loop. Thanks though. This is useful for future coding.

Comment: But why is it that you want one loop? The condition has to be evaluated at every cycle, so a single outer if and a simpler condition might actually result in better performance.

Comment: Ya, agreed. But at my end, the challenge was to make a program in least characters :) . So an extra for loop costs a lot in that way. But agreed to your conclusion of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is only a bad condition:

```
for(i=a;(a<b?i<=b:i>=b);(a>b?i--:i++))
{
   ...
}
```

instead of `a>b` in your code should be `a<b`

Comment: I realised as I posted and edited.. Thanks, but its not working.